# Which country has better road traffic safety, Japan or USA?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, risk

This is more a question about how to weigh several **statistical numbers**. Or, which statiscal measure does exist to properly compare these two countries on this matter of road traffic safety?

```
filler   deaths per   deaths per    deaths per    ---filler-- 
Country  1 mill ppl   10 bill km    100K cars     population   
USA__     103           68            12          325,250,000   
Japan      40           69             6          126,920,000
```

Which country has better road traffic safety, Japan or USA? At first glance, it seems obviously Japan, 40 per 1 million people. But looking at it per vehicle kilometres, USA has about the same number of deaths. Does this mean that the USA is safer, as safe as, or less safe than Japan??

Put another way:
I know there is a method to attach weights to this so that we can properly compare the 2 countries, but I don't know **how** to do the weighing.

I'm having a brain freeze and I can't figure it out.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_traffic_safety

Comment: Safer is a term that could be interpreted many ways.  When I first read the title I thought it might have to do with enemy threats (terrorism).,  It could also death rate by various causes ,  But you mean traffic safety.  So maybe  you should put that in the title.

Comment: As @MichaelChernick says, there's no objective answer without defining "safer". If you're twice as likely to die in a car every time you get in one in Japan than the US, but you have to get in a car four times as often, which one is safer?

Comment: @JeremyMiles And ThAT is exactly what I am asking! How can we devise a way to properly compare these two countries?

For example: We could say Japan is a healthier country because it has 39,000 lethal heart attacks and the US has 100,000, but when you realize that Japan also is 39% of the US population, so the  lethal heart attack rate is exactly the same.

Comment: Then I would say that they are equal on heart attack safety - because the chance of dying of a heart attack is the same.

Comment: But for travel, it's not clear what the denominator is when you say "safer" so I don't think there is a single answer.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I thought it was obvious that it's number of deaths. My question is partly about what is the best denominator, people, drivers, cars, vehicle kms or something else.